# What happened to Molly's mother?

Tags: pokemon

In *Spell of the Unknown* we are told that Molly's mother disappeared some time before the film. At the end of the film, [Spencer appears with a woman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgTOYHtN5M4&t=160s) who has a similar sort of hat to what Molly's mother has in the photograph.

[image: Photograph][image: End Credits Woman]

After seeing them, we see Molly mouth something (sorta looks like Mama) and rush into the woman's arms. Given how much Molly loves her mother he can probably assume this is her actual mother and not some woman who would become Molly's step-mother.

But then what happened to Molly's mother that would cause her to disappear before the film, and then all of a sudden be found at the end?

Comment: I have seen that many years ago!

Answer (score 2):

Although never explained in the film, the guidebooks released with the Japanese version of the film reveal that she was hospitalised before the events of the film as per [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Molly_Hale).

Answer (score 0):

Since the Unown took both of her parents, it makes sense that when the Unown disappeared, they both came back.

Comment: My understanding is that the Unown only took her father, and her mother disappeared separately. JQL's answer backs this up.